# jQuery validation plugin and server-side php validation

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I have a question regarding the php validation, I have this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// validate signup form on keyup and submit
var validator = $("#contactform").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            email: true,
            required: true,
            remote: { url: "test.php", type: "post" }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email: {
            email: "Enter a valid email adress",
            required: "This input is required",
            remote: "Email adress is in use"
        }
    },
    // set this class to error-labels to indicate valid fields
    success: function(label) {
        label.addClass("checked");
    }
});
});
```

and the validation script from test.php is

```
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))); 
require_once (__ROOT__.'/config.php');

$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$SQL = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    If($SQL->num_rows == 0) {
        echo 'true';
    } else {
        echo 'false';
    }
```

How can I make the validation from the php file to be more complex like: I want to add a rule to check if the email is valid ( just in case someone don't have javascript active ) but if I try something like this the validation script wont return me an error message if the email address is in the database

```
If(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false) {
$SQL = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    If($SQL->num_rows == 0) {
        echo 'true';
    } else {
        echo 'false';
    }
}
```

Comment: The validation breaks how? PHP error, MySQL error, not expecting the correct output .. etc ?

Comment: If I type in the form an email address that exist in the database it wont return me the error.

Comment: That exist or **not** exist in the database?

Comment: " I want to add a rule to check if the email is valid ( just in case someone don't have javascript active )" So, you want to validate the email format from server side or what? didn't FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL do that?

Comment: @dbf that exist in the database

Comment: @OscarJara yes it does but the remote from the ajax wont work

Comment: @Netra Ok, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems around the `remote` usage with `jquery.validate`. Check if you did the following:

**1)** Make sure you are using jQuery version ***1.6.1*** and above only.

**2)** Use the "synchronous" option for remote execution (default being asynchronous) and set `async` option to `false`.

**Usage:**

```
$("#contactform").validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: { url:"check.php", async:false }
    }
  }
});
```